More than 1000 color product attribute options Issue on Page Performance - Magento 2
I need some advice on how to optimize the 1000 product attribute options in our store. For example, we have 1000 color options, but according to Magento 2, we can only assign a maximum of 100. Assigning more than that will negatively impact the page performance.
According to Magento's official guide, Adobe suggests the following approach: "Build specific product templates with targeting attributes and options to avoid generalized product templates and option containers."
Here's the link for more information: https://experienceleague.adobe.com/en/docs/commerce-operations/implementation-playbook/best-practices/planning/catalog-management?lang=en#product-attributes
Please suggest if have any idea on it?

Hey, please remove the ajax tag
